# xmlreader reads every second step

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to serialize an XMLfile and i am facing some issue. Look below at my xml sample file:

```
<Information xmlns="dis">
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>4</signal>
    <tresh>RTX</tresh>
    <obb>GGHUI</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>3</signal>
    <tresh>RTR</tresh>
    <obb>GGH</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>20</signal>
    <tresh>WWRTX</tresh>
    <obb>BBHUI</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    <SOS.Alert>
    <signal>13</signal>
    <tresh>DRTR</tresh>
    <obb>GFH</obb>
    </SOS.Alert>
    ....
</Information>
```

The problem is it's skipping every "second". So if we we have 4 inputs like above only two will be serialized:

```
<SOS.Alert>
<signal>4</signal>
<tresh>RTX</tresh>
<obb>GGHUI</obb>
</SOS.Alert>
<SOS.Alert>
<signal>20</signal>
<tresh>WWRTX</tresh>
<obb>BBHUI</obb>
</SOS.Alert>
```

This is the code i am using:

```
Me.xmlreader = New XmlTextReader(inputFileName)


            Me.xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
            While (Me.xmlreader.Read())
                If ((Me.xmlreader.Name = "SOS.Alert") And (Me.xmlreader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element) And (Me.xmlreader.IsStartElement())) Then

                    Me.data.MyList.Add(xmlreader.ReadOuterXml)
                End If

            End While
```

Note that i want to stay with XMLTeamReader because I am operating on big XML file more than 1,5gb and XDocument, XElement and others are not taken under consideration as they loading entire XML to memory therefore OutoOfMemory exception.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the `ReadOuterXml` call. Take a look at this MSDN article, specifically the Remarks table that shows "Position After the call": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It shows that with this XML:

```
  <item1>text1</item1><item2>text2</item2>
```

If you call `ReadOuterXml` while within Item1, it will move the reader Forward to Item2. Because this happens within the loop, your reader will progress forward again and be past the start tag to your second item. This will cause you to "skip"

Answer (score 0):

After ReadOuterXml, the reader is already located at your next desired node, your second SOS.Alert. But because of the `Me.xmlreader.Read()` call, the next item in the xml is read, `signal`. That is one too far. Now you read the nodes util you see the third SOS.Alert.
I think you need the code below. After finding your first SOS.Alert, it will continue to read SOS.Alert branches until the end.

```
        Me.xmlreader = New XmlTextReader(inputFileName)
        Me.xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None
        While (Me.xmlreader.Read())
            If ((Me.xmlreader.Name = "SOS.Alert") And (Me.xmlreader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element) And (Me.xmlreader.IsStartElement())) Then
                While  ((Me.xmlreader.Name = "SOS.Alert") And (Me.xmlreader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element) And (Me.xmlreader.IsStartElement())) 
                    Me.data.MyList.Add(xmlreader.ReadOuterXml)
                End While
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Using my old code it finishing (of course with second step issue) on 221155 th line. I implemented you code and i received this exception after a while: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dl". Anyhow i checked first couple rows and it seems its taking every row. How to avoid that error?

Comment: You are reading more than 1.5 GB of data and you store in into `data` (`Me.data.MyList.Add`). It might be possible that MyList cannot handle it. Remember that when using your old code, your list will contain the half of what it contains using the new code. Maybe you can change your program in such a way that you handle the result directly before storing it into a list; in that case you do not need so much memory. You can use a memory profiler which object(s) is/are responsible for excessive memory load. If you don't have it: there are trial versions. Then try to fix it (or ask for help again).

Comment: With the file size that you are using, you are probably an issue with the Large Object Heap (LOH). This part of the heap is collected by the GC, but not defragmented. During addition of items on a list, the capacity is increased by allocating new memory with double space, and the array/list is copied. A solution for this is to pre-allocate the expected number of items in the List constructor (`Dim list As New List(Of String)(1000000)`). You might require a higher capacity, but remember, arrays (and lists are arrays) cannot go beyond 2GB, even on x64 (.Net4.5 has a solution).

Comment: problem is every line have to be put into the list because later i am store it in database. Can you advice some solution for that issue?

Comment: You could do two things. (1) After read the OuterXml, put it directly in the DB. (2) You can read the individual tags (the entries for signal, tresh and obb) and declare a class/struct for that. Now you are allocating complete strings and that takes more memory. For example, if you have 1024 entries, 30kB is spent to store '<signal>' and </signal>' (each char is 2 bytes), while the values would take 4kB (or 8kB on x64). It is not needed to store the tags. This could reduce memory load considerably.

Comment: i know i could use direct put to db every line straightaway but i am doing additional things with those strings after there are putted to list compicated operations. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have other ideas. I think it is better to start a new question in SO because you have now a different problem (OutOfMemory exceptions when accessing large files). This will bring the problem under the attention of more people (hopefully people who are specialized in this). If your first problem (xmlReader skips each second line) is solved (and it appears to be) please be so kind to upvote it/mark it as solution.

Comment: btw what is the maximum size of List and is there any possibility to check the size over each loop?

Comment: Property `Count` returns the number of items. I expect that each time in the loop size increments with 1. The maximum size of the indexer is in theory MAX_INT: 2,147,483,647. But the total array size (a list is also an array) cannot exceed 2GB. Therefore, the max. number of elements depends on the type parameter of the list. There is also a property 'Capacity' which returns the number of pre-allocated elements. If all items are in use, the addition of a new item will result in an array relocation, with `Capacity` doubled. This array relocation is most probably the problem.

Comment: So maybe the resolution would be to check list capacity how should i check it? If list.capacity > ??

Comment: It is better to specify the capacity that you expect in the List constructor. But the moment when your app breaks depends on more factors, such as installed memory and memory usage of other apps. You explained already that you need to do more with the data but still I think that adding them to a database in your loop is best. Databases are designed to handle huge blocks of data, in contrast to the List objects. After adding them in the DB, you still can access data in the DB. You could consider adding the  OuterXml fragments itself in the DB, and later process it.